# Alphabetically sorting a dictionary of basketball teams

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble sorting a dictionary alphabetically.
So far I have tried various methods but I keep running into errors;

The list in need of sorting by Team name:

```
NBA_teams = {'Atlanta': 'Hawks','Chicago':'Bulls', 'Los Angeles':'Lakers', 'Miami':'Heat', 'Phoenix': 'Suns', 'Toronto': 'Raptors'}

# Method so far:

for i in sorted (NBA_teams) :
    print ((i, NBA_teams[i], end = " "))
```

Ive also tried lambda but I end up running into this error;

```
print(sorted(NBA_teams.items(), key = lambda kv:(kv[1], kv[0])))
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Is there any way to fix either of these so that I can sort the above dictionary by either Team or Location?

Comment: That second method works. If it doesn't, that means you've overwritten the variable `NBA_teams` somewhere in your experiments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sorted`:

```
NBA_teams = {'Atlanta': 'Hawks',
             'Chicago':'Bulls',
             'Los Angeles':'Lakers',
             'Miami':'Heat',
             'Phoenix': 'Suns',
             'Toronto': 'Raptors'
             }

for loc in sorted(NBA_teams.keys()):
    print(loc + ': ' + NBA_teams[loc])
```

Giving the basketball teams, sorted by location alphabetically:

```
Atlanta: Hawks
Chicago: Bulls
Los Angeles: Lakers
Miami: Heat
Phoenix: Suns
Toronto: Raptors
```

Sorted by team name alphabetically:

```
for loc, team in sorted(NBA_teams.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1], kv[0])):
    print(loc, team)
```

Returns:

```
Chicago Bulls
Atlanta Hawks
Miami Heat
Los Angeles Lakers
Toronto Raptors
Phoenix Suns
```